# Problem starting heroku: get Invalid char '\024' error in log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am working through the ruby on rails tutorial. I have all of the test passing and deployed to git hub.

When I deployed to Heroku and opened the online application it tells me something went wrong.

I looked at the log files and this is what was written:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (compile error
  /app/app/views/pages/home.html.erb:10: Invalid char \024' in expression):
            <%= render "shared/feed" %>
            </td>
            <td class="sidebar round">
            <%= render "shared/user_info" %>
        </tr>
     </table>
     <% else %>     
   app/views/pages/home.html.erb:23:in `compile'
```

any ideas how to fix this error?

Comment: Could you add code of the home.html.erb view to your question

Comment: are both local and heroku app using the same ruby version?

Comment: I had an HTML comment which when I removed it stopped the error from occuring. I don't understand why as I have html comment tags in the application elsewhere and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had some "null" values instead of null in my database which was causing the problem. Once I cleared those out everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

this may sound silly but after you deploy the app did ran 
heroku rake db:migrate 
also make sure you close that if statement with <% end %>

Answer (score 0):

make sure your code has no "special" encoded characters (ex: from copy and paste...)...

Comment: Thanks the only one I had was <!-- comment --> which when removed fixed the problem.